# Writing a divorce GET on sand

Tags: halacha, divorce

If a divorce GET (document) is written on loose sand in a box and delivered to the woman, is this a kosher GET and valid divorce?

The writing would hold in the sand, though if the box holding the sand is tipped too much to one side, the get would be erased.

Comment: There would be 3 issues to consider. 1. It’s being written with something that isn’t long lasting which according to many, is passul. 2. It’s being carved out instead of written, which is not recommended according to Rama 125:4. 3. Assuming there are witnesses to confirm the writing at the time of giving it, the Rama 124:2 brings some who say if it's written on something that doesn’t last it’s passul

Answer (score 2):

The Rambam in Hilchos Gerushin 4:1 writes that things that don't leave a permanent impression cannot be used such as drinks ,fruit juice and similar type items. The Mishna in shabbos 12:5 writes that writing on sand(see Bartanura who explains that is what avak derachim is)would be patur from the issur of writing on shabbos. It seems from these sources that sand would not be a valid means of writing a get.

Text from Taz 125:1 :שרישומו ניכר פירוש הרושם מתקיים וניכר תמיד לאפוקי מדבר שאינו מתקיים כמו משקין ומי פירות

See also the the Bach on the Tur siman 125 which discusses a possible difference between the the Tur and the Rambam whether one needs just to recognize the letters  or that it needs to be permanent as well.

Comment: Sand does leave a permanent impression as long as you don't wipe it away, unlike fruit juice that disappears of its own accord when it dries.

Comment: With a slight wind sand can move

Comment: @magicker the mishna in shabbat as understood by bartenura indicates that is not considered permanent, at least as regards the laws of shabbat

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that needs to be clarified is ON what was it written. I'm assuming you are talking about a scenario where the sand is carved out of sand sitting in a box, not a case of using sand to write letters on a klaf.

According to the [Rama 124:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.124.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) it should be written ON something that has lasting power;

> וי"א דוקא בדבר שהוא של קיימא אבל אם כתב בעלה של בצלים או ירקות וכדומה לזה פסול (הר"ן פ"ב)

Writing on (or in) sand, is debatable if it can be considered lasting.

Another point to consider is how the letters are formed. If they carved out (as my assumption) then perhaps it would be good, however if they are embossed it would be problematic. The [Shulchan Aruch 125:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.125.4?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) mentions this

> חקק גט על הלוח או על האבן או על טס של מתכת אם חפר יריכי האותיות כשר וכן אם חקק יריכי האותיות מאחורי הטס עד שבלטו בפני הטס אבל אם חפר תוך האות עד שיראו היריכות גבוהות מכאן ומכאן או שהכה על פני הטס בחותם עד שנמצאו האותיות בולטות כדרך שעושין דינר זהב אינו גט: הגה י"א דלכתחילה יש להחמיר שלא לכתוב בקולמוס של ברזל שלא לבא לידי חקיקה (סדר גיטין) וע"ל סי' זה סעיף כ"ב ולא מקרי חק תוכות אלא כשכל האות נעשה כך אבל אם צריך עדיין לתקן שיהיה אות כשר (ת"ה סי' רכ"ח)

Finally, there is the main issue of writing with something that is not long lasting. The cases that are used as examples in Shulchan Aruch and elsewhere, are about fruit juices and the like, things that will fade on their own over time. Sand, if left alone will remain as is. However, since it can be easily erased, there will have to be witnesses at the time of giving that will attest to what was written. Yet, we can perhaps learn from Hilchos Shabbos where the poskim include sand as the same as fruit juice

The [Shulchan Aruch 340:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.340.4?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) says that one should not write in fruit juices or ashes, the [Mishna Berura 340:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.340.20?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) mentions that the same issur would apply to sand. So, for Shabbos, writing in sand would be assur M'drabbanan, just like fruit juices.

There might be another point to consider from Hilchos Shabbos, that since it is only assur M'drabbanan it is not good enough for a Get;

The Gemara in [Gittin 19A](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.19a.11?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) says in the name of R' Yochanon;

> א"ל והלא לימדתנו רבינו כתב עליון כתב לענין שבת א"ל וכי מפני שאנו מדמין נעשה מעשה

Rashi there explains that even on Shabbos, such a writing would not bring a Korban. Seemingly, a ksav that is only assur M'drabbanan on Shabbos is not good enough for a Get.